# How to retrieve meta data for share from Wikipedia?

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-opengraph, wikipedia

There is an Open Graph Meta Tag to share via SNS. I know that Open Graph is usually used for sharing. But, I can not find Open Graph Meta Tag from Wikipedia articles. But, I tried to share Wikipedia Article from Google Plus and Facebook, It shows very well just like using Open Graph Meta Tags.

Could you tell me how to retrieve meta data from Wikipedia articles? Is there a special method for Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia articles do not currently contain any Open Graph tags. It's therefore safe to assume that the information embedded in a Facebook share of a Wikipedia page (for example) is collected the old-fashioned way, the way Facebook has been doing it since before they published Open Graph in an effort to improve the process: By parsing it out of the page source.

While it's not as streamlined and structured as with Open Graph, parsed shares are manageable since there isn't really all that much [meta]data that goes into a "legacy" Facebook share. The Title is taken directly from the HTML <TITLE> entity, the source/author/publisher is the site hostname, and then best-guess efforts are made to identify body text for the snippet, and the image (or images, as they sometimes capture several candidates for the sharer to choose among) to use as the share thumbnail.

It *usually* works well enough, as you observe — generated HTML is predictable — but not always, especially (in the case of Wikipedia) where images are concerned. As an example, this is how the [Wikipedia "Uranus" article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranus) appears in a Facebook share:

[image]

There's a photo of the planet in the article's Infobox, but that's a deeply-buried (from an HTML source perspective), right-aligned element that Facebook's parser frequently misses. And since Wikipedia's content is overwhelmingly prose-centric, many other articles contain no images at all. Facebook's parser often uses a left-aligned illustration from somewhere in the article body (as happened here), or even one of the Wikimedia Project icons in the page footer, as the "thumbnail" on Wikipedia shares.

Comment: Apologies for the fact that this goes a little afield of your original question, in explaining that there isn't really a method for doing exactly what you asked. Oh, and by way of disclosure/disclaimer, I'm in the planning/research stages of a proposal to add OG tags to Wikipedia pages (which is how I found your question), in hopes of improving on the above. I found that by adding just a few easily-generated header lines to a mirror of the "Uranus" page, I was able to take it from the above, to this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2b59xf2Khp3WHduZFYwcW4ySkU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @törzsmókus To be honest, I've kind of let that fall by the wayside, mostly due to changes at Wikipedia. They now do include `og:image` tags on article pages, to explicitly specify the primary image. (It's the only one of the Open Graph tags exported, but in practice the other data can be scraped easily.) As a result, a share of that same [Uranus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranus) article today looks like this: http://imgur.com/a/l0opl ...Which feels kind of "good enough".